# Apollo cache redirect for field with no arguments

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a login mutation tha looks similiar to this:

```
mutation login($password: String!, $email: String) {
  login(password: $password, email: $email) {
    jwt
    user {
      account {
        id
        email
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On the other hand, I have a query for getting the account details. The backend verifies which user it is by means of the JWT token that is send with the request, so no need for sending the account id as an argument.

```
query GetUser {
  user {
    account {
      id
      email
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I am facing is now: Apollo is making a network request every time as GetUser has no argument. I would prever to query from cache first. So I thought, I could redirect as described [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#cache-redirects-using-field-policy-read-functions).

First, I was facing the issue that user field does not return an id directly so I have defined a type policy as such:

```
const typePolicies: TypePolicies = {
  User: {
    keyFields: ["account", ["id"]],
  },
}
```

So regarding the redirect I have add the following to the type policy:

```
const typePolicies: TypePolicies = {
  User: {
    keyFields: ["account", ["id"]],
  },
  Query: {
    fields: {
      user(_, { toReference }) {
        return toReference({
          __typename: "User",
          account: {
            id: "1234",
          },
        })
      },
    },
  },
}
```

This works, however there is a fixed id of course. Is there any way to solve this issue by always redirecting to the user object that was queried during login?

Or is it better to add the id as argument to the GetUser  query?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this by means of the readField function:

```
  Query: {
    fields: {
      user(_, { toReference, readField }) {
        return readField({
          fieldName: "user",
          from: toReference({
            __typename: "LoginMutationResponse",
            errors: null,
          }),
        })
      },
    },
  },
```

What happens if the reference cannot be found? It seems like apollo is not making a request then. Is that right? How can this be solved?

I have noticed this in my tests as the login query is not executed.